# Assign the value of a property based on another property in model ASP.NET Core MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What I want to do, as the title says, is assign a value to a property of the model, based on on another property.

In my specific case, what I want to do is assign the property `blongmonth` (which is a string, for example "January") to `bmonth` (which is the number of the month, in this case would be `1`, and is an integer). I have to work with this types, since I am working on a table which I cannot modify.

The problem is, the harder I try, I cannot find a working solution, and online I don't find nothing specific which helps me solving my little problem. When, in my app, I select (from a dropdown menu) the month (`blongmonth`), the number of the month (`bmonth`) in the database is always "0".

I've tried creating a method in the ViewModel and calling it in the Model (not a good idea) but doesn't work, as the ViewModel is only to present data. Now I'm trying to do the thing directly in the model:

```
public class Bdgfixmonth
{
    [Key]
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Byear { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Bbudget { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    //public int Bmonth { get; set; }
    private int _Bmonth;
    public int Bmonth 
    { 
        get
        {
             return _Bmonth;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Blongmonth == "January")
            {
                _Bmonth = 1;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "February")
            {
                _Bmonth = 2;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "March")
            {
                _Bmonth = 3;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "April")
            {
                _Bmonth = 4;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "May")
            {
                _Bmonth = 5;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "June")
            {
                _Bmonth = 6;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "July")
            {
                _Bmonth = 7;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "August")
            {
                _Bmonth = 8;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "September")
            {
                _Bmonth = 9;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "October")
            {
                _Bmonth = 10;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "November")
            {
                _Bmonth = 11;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "December")
            {
                _Bmonth = 12;
            }
            else
            {
                _Bmonth = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    [Required]
    public string Blongmonth 
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Closed { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Current { get; set; }
}
```

I tried also putting this code in the getter of `Blongmonth`, creating also a private variable, but it doesn't work. Also tried this way:

```
if (Blongmonth == "January")
{
    _Bmonth = 1;
    _Bmonth = Bmonth;
}
```

This is the dropdown menu in the Create View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Blongmonth" class="control-label">@ViewBag.D</label>
            <select asp-for="Blongmonth" class="form-control" asp-action="">
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="July">July</option>
                <option value="August">August</option>
                <option value="September">September</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="November">November</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Blongmonth" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

I also tried creating a trigger directly in SQL Server but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    bmonth, 
    CASE
        WHEN blongmonth = 'January' THEN 1
        ELSE 'False'
    END
FROM bdgfixmonth
```

If I choose January in this test, it will go to "false".

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I have to to this in the controller? I am a humble beginner, I would appreciate if someone more experienced than me could help me.

Comment: You can get the month name from CultureInfo class or DateTime.ParseExact().Month;

Comment: Think Simply. 
Set option value to 1,2,3,4 etc for each option inside select box in View and when you insert / update corresponding value in DB convert value into INT and save.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the backing _Bmonth variable if the value is entirely determined by another field. What you have in your setter code, move it to the get and just return should work. Also, no need for a set if you never assign to it:

```
public int Bmonth
    {
        get
        {
            if (Blongmonth == "January")
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "February")
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "March")
            {
                return 3;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "April")
            {
                return 4;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "May")
            {
                return 5;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "June")
            {
                return 6;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "July")
            {
                return 7;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "August")
            {
                return 8;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "September")
            {
                return 9;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "October")
            {
                return 10;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "November")
            {
                return 11;
            }
            else if (Blongmonth == "December")
            {
                return 12;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```